# Use information of a previous GraphQL mutation in the same query

Tags: javascript, graphql, keystonejs, gqlquery

I want to run a single query with multiple mutations, but I need to reference the data from a previous mutations is that possible?

```
mutation {
  venue1: createVenue(data: { name: "Test Venue 1", active: true }) {
    id
  }
  layout1: createLayout(
    data: { name: "Test Layout 1", active: true, venue: { connect: (I WANT TO USE venue1) } }
  ) {
    id
  }
}
```

This is a over-simplification of what I'm trying to do, I'll need to use a single query to seed a DB for testing purposes, and using `create` instead of `connect` won't be enough because there are required relations and elements which require multiple relations, so it need to be lineal to fill all of those relations.

Comment: it is possible as root mutations are guaranteed to run sequentially/preserving order ... try `parent.venue1` in `createLayout` resolver or use context to save/read/pass data between resolvers

Comment: parent.venue1 get's me an error, do you have more info on how can I use the context? I don't have control over the graphql resolver

Comment: both methods are for resolvers/backend/api